# Is it possible to have a CSS selector based on a CSS property (and its value)?

Tags: css, css-selectors

For example, I want a CSS selector for all `div` elements which have a CSS `overflow:auto;` property. Is it possible to have a selector of that kind?

Comment: What if (and it will be for standard stylesheet application) a CSS selector was one that applied the CSS property? :}

Comment: @user2864740 Actually I want to use [this jquery plugin](http://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/), so I'd like to apply this scrollbar to any `div` on the site having the `overflow:auto` property at-once.

Comment: Then use the jQuery plugin :}

Comment: @user2864740 :s Yeah, but I wanted to do something like `$("div[overflow:auto]").niceScroll();` rather than looking for all the div's in the site to find the ones which have `overflow:auto` property, and then calling `niceScroll()` on them.

Comment: A custom jQuery/Sizzle selector "could" possibly be written, but .. that would be an exercise in cleverness, not practicality.

Comment: @user2864740 - well that is something a developer should **avoid**, just like avoiding *endless while loop* and many other things one must avoid. just add that to the pile, not a show-stopped for this wonderful feature with so much potential.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. There's no way to do this with css. You need to use scripting language.

But if you have defined style in your html like the following then this would be possible like:

```css
div[style="overflow:auto;"]{
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
    <div style="overflow:auto;">overflow is auto</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Note that `style="overflow:auto;"` will match divs which has exact that CSS (string). If you want to select divs that *contains* `overflow:auto` along with some other css, you can use `*` selector.

```
div[style*="overflow:auto;"]{
  background-color: #f00;
}
```